# Change the div id's below a given div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

So I am creating an interactive form.
I want to be able to add new inputs above and below a given selection.
However, when I do this, I need to update the id's and labels of everything below the new entry.
I know I can use the each() function to go through all of the div's, however, I'm sure it would be faster to just update below what needs to be updated, especially if there are several input fields.

Here's what I have so far.

```
<form>
  <div id="ent1" class="entry">
    <span class="label">1. </span>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="deleteentry(this);"> Delete </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addabove(this);"> Add above </button><br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ent2" class="entry">
    <span class="label">2. </span>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="deleteentry(this);"> Delete </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addabove(this);"> Add above </button><br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ent3" class="entry">
    <span class="label">3. </span>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="deleteentry(this);"> Delete </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addabove(this);"> Add above </button><br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ent4" class="entry">
    <span class="label">4. </span>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="deleteentry(this);"> Delete </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addabove(this);"> Add above </button><br><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here are the scripts.

```
<script>
function deleteentry(obj)
{
  var o = obj;
  while (!o.id)
  {
    o = o.parentNode;
  }

  obj = "#" + o.id;
  $(obj).remove();
}

function addabove(abo)
{
  var a = abo;
  while (!a.id)
  {
    a = a.parentNode;
  }

  var anum = a.id.replace(/\D/g,'');
  anum = parseInt(anum);

  var b = a.id; //This is so the div clicked on has a new temp id and no 2 divs share the same id
  a.id = "temp";

  var ins1 = "<div id='" + b + "' class='entry'>";
  var ins2 = "<span class='label'>" + anum + ". </span>";
  var ins3 = "<input type='text'> <button type='button' onclick='deleteentry(this);'> Delete </button> ";
  var ins4 = "<button type='button' onclick='addabove(this);'> Add above </button>" + b + "<br><br></div>";

  $(a).prepend(ins1 + ins2 + ins3 + ins4);
}
```

So let's say you click add above for entry `.2`, how I do access **only** the divs below the `ent2` divs?

Comment: Please consider moving to [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript) (rather than using in-line event-handlers, `onclick` and so forth).

Comment: Could you please give me a code example of how this would look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MikelG - please see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rk73F/

There are 2 functions there for getting ID + extracted your addAbove one..
Also removed your onclick events, i find that jquery .on click or .live clicks are better.. you may have to change those handlers definition based on what version of jquery is being used..

**UPDATED (twice)**

New fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rk73F/2/

```
function getMaxID() {
var ar = new Array();
// for each element with id that starts with 'ent'
$('[id^="ent"]').each(

function () {
    // add it to the array (only its numeric part)
    ar.push(
    // extract the numeric part to be added in the array
    parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('ent', '')));
});
// find the max value in the array 
return Math.max.apply(Math, ar);
}

function addAbove(abo) {
var b = getMaxID() + 1;

var ins1 = "<div id='ent" + b + "' class='entry'>";
var ins2 = "<span class='label'>" + b + ". </span>";
var ins3 = "<input type='text'> <button type='button' class='btnDelete'> Delete </button> ";
var ins4 = "<button type='button' class='btnAdd'> Add above </button><br><br></div>";
$(abo).before(ins1 + ins2 + ins3 + ins4);
}

function setDivsSequentialIDs()
{
$.each($('form>div'), function( ind, val ){
    $(this).attr('id', 'ent' + ind);
    $(this).find('span.label').html(ind + '.');
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
//NEW:
$('form').on('click', '.btnAdd', function () {
    addAbove($(this).parent());
});

$('form').on('click', '.btnDelete', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
//EndNEW
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle JF, this is close to what I'm going after.  The only issue is that when you add new entries, the label order is not properly updated.  I'd really like to keep it sequential, hence why I wanted to update the id's and labels for all the divs below.

Comment: @MikelG Updated it - added setDivsSequentialIDs() function to iterate through each div thats in the form and update its id to the index..

Comment: agh, updated again sorry forgot `ent` in the ID's .. see updated fiddle /2/ @MikelG

Comment: lemmie know if u need anything else @MikelG i gotta go for the weekend in like 20 mins.. lol

Comment: Hey sorry for getting back to you so late JF, I'm at work and had to actually "work" lol.  I'm looking at your code now.  The fiddle works as I'd like, just would like it to start at 1.  I'm going to try to figure it out though. This is far beyond the help I expected, so thank you!

Comment: Was able to figure it out.  Only thing is that, I'm using jquery 1.10 from googleapis and the code above won't work unless I go to 1.8.3.  What exactly needs to be changed for this to work with 1.10?

Comment: @MikelG  Hey - see my updated answer - i changed 'live' clicks to "on" .. Live is depreciated and was removed after 1.8 or something close to that.

Comment: Thank you @JF it, you have been more help than I expected.  I've been working on this for days, being a noob at this.  Wanted to truly put in the work before asking for help, and you have gone above and beyond. Seriously, thank you!!

Comment: @MikelG :) NP Mikel Glad to be of help.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you with this @JF it, but I've ran into one more problem. I've updated the code, but now, neither of the buttons of the new entries function at all. I'm not sure why this is the case. Could you please be of assistance?

Comment: @MikelG Yep, Post your edits into the question, as much html/js as possible :) if you could replicate it into a jsfiddle that would be even better.

Comment: here is the fiddle.  As you can see, neither button works on the new entries.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the ready function, but I'm really not sure. 

http://jsfiddle.net/rk73F/3/

Comment: Perfect give me a few mins.

Comment: @MikelG Fixed : your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rk73F/4/  Marked the lines I changed with `//changed` comments. My bad - the fiddle I gave you should have had its events defined like that from the get go. Let me know if you have any further difficulty.

Comment: once again a pleasure :) let me know of any more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#your-id').next()` to access elements below the selected element and `$('#your-div').prev()` to access elements above.

See http://api.jquery.com/next/ and http://api.jquery.com/prev/ for more info.

Comment: But wouldn't that just choose the <span> element?  Further, I need to repeat this process for every div below it, how would I make it loop?

Comment: next + prev only get one element, you'd need to use nextAll and prevAll to get arrays of every element before/after.

Comment: I understand, but how do you get only the div elements and not every element?

Comment: gimmie a sec finishing off a fiddle.. @MikelG

Comment: Haha, I forgot to delete that. That button was used for adding more entries at the bottom and I was just learning jquery functions.  I'll edit it out.  Sorry.